# AngularJS $q and promises and assignment confusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variable-assignment, q, angular-promise

So, I'm wondering why I'm seeing this particular behavior.  I'm not sure if I don't understand something about how promises work, or JavaScript, or Angular, but here's what's happening (I have this plnkr set up to demonstrate - http://plnkr.co/edit/ZKXkUv?p=preview):

```
<html ng-app="queue">
<head>
  <title>$q resolves for no one</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module('queue', ['ngResource'])
      .controller('queueCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', function($scope, $q)
      {

        var _funk = true;
        $scope.testing2;

        var deferred = $q(function(resolve, reject)
        {
          if (_funk) {
            resolve({funk: 'yes'});
          } else {
            reject({funk: 'no'});
          }
        });

        deferred.then(function(resolved){
          console.log(resolved.funk)
        }, function(rejected){
          console.log(rejected);
        })

        function defReuse()
        {
          var toBeRet = {};
          deferred.then(function(resolved){
            console.log('yea')
            $scope.testing2 = resolved;
            angular.copy(resolved, toBeRet);
          }, function(rejected){
            toBeRet = rejected;
          })
          return toBeRet;
        }

        $scope.testing = defReuse();

      }]);
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="queueCtrl">
  {{testing.funk}}
  {{testing2.funk}}
</body>
</html>
```

I need to get a value out of what's returned in a promise. I assumed the easiest way to do this was via assignment to something outside the promise object. If you look in the plnkr you'll see that I'm successfully getting the value out by either assigning to a $scope variable, or by using angular.copy().  I cannot, however, successfully assign directly to the variable that's being returned in the defReuse() function, which is odd.  I should add in here that I've declared the toBeRet variable I'm trying to assign to in the global scope as well with the same result.

So, the question is why?  Is there something I'm overlooking about the $scope variable?  Or how Angular works?  Or how promises work?  It's a bit of a mystery at the moment..

Comment: By the time defReuse() executes and returns toBeRet, the toBeRet is empty. Since async request is incomplete in background & takes time to populate toBeRet.

Comment: @VVK the only problem with this answer is that if I change toBeRet to be a variable in global scope and simply assign but do not return, the assignment still isn't happening. Also, since toBeRet is an object in this context, there should be a reference to it right? So when the promise does resolve it should still assign to the object and in that way to the $scope.testing variable, correct?

Comment: By looking at plnkr. It is showing correct result. The success function of your defer is returning **funk: "yes"**. And you are printing **testing.funk**

Comment: Yes, that's right. But the testing.funk assignment only happens if I use Angular.copy(), which was the question - why this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

`$q` in angular help us to run the function asynchronously. This return promise and once it resolve the respective `then` method get called. Please go through some of the following link to understand $q and promise in angular

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q
- http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/